# [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package imported

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I would like to change import from `../../../db/index.js` to `db/index.js`

[image]

I have already added this setting in my jsconfig.json but I still got this error.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working in my client folder (react app). This is on my server folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the right answer after trying different kinds of approaches.
Eslint import resolver and babel import resolver seem to be not working.

Add the ff:

*package.json*

```
"imports": {
    "#root/*": {
        "default": "./src/*"
    }
},
```

If you want to access that import directy via ctr+click/left click create *jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "#root/*": ["./*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Usage in your *index.js*:

```
import level1 from '#root/level1/index.js';
```

instead of:

```
import level1 from './level1/index.js';
```

https://marian-caikovski.medium.com/4-ways-to-avoid-double-dots-in-module-specifiers-f5b6086cd9d1

Answer (score 0):

These are two very different things:

`import { something } from '../../something'` - local import (file you've created)

`import { something } from 'something'` - import from a package (e.g. installed with `yarn add something`

If you'd like to clean up your imports and be able to do something like:

`import { something } from '@components/something'` then you need additional plugins/setup. It's worth looking into `babel-plugin-root-import` for example.

There might be other plugins/tools to do that but I've never had the need do do that so I don't know.

Comment: Still the same. I have followed all the instructions. I think there is a problem in node I have tried to clone projects but still error is the same when running the project. https://github.com/thatanjan/nodejs-setup.git

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a repo that'd reproduce the issue you're having?

Comment: Finally fixed the issue. I have added these in my package.json "imports": {
    "#root/*": {
        "default": "./src/*"
    }
},